# How to know the type of a value returned by a Redshift query?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

In PostgreSQL, you can use the funtion `pg_typeof()` within the SELECT statement to get the data type of a value returned by a SQL query.

This function does not exist in Redshift, despite Redshift's SQL lineage.

I want to do this:

`SELECT pg_typeof(0.25::numeric(5,2)) ;`

and get:

`numeric(5,2)`

How do I get the data type of a value returned by a SQL query?
This is to help me with unit-testing my ETL development.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to check the column type in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if can be used in you use case, but I use this query to get the types in Redshift

```
SELECT distinct 
        t.relname as table,
        a.attname as column,
        pg_catalog.format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod) as type
FROM pg_attribute a
    JOIN pg_class t on a.attrelid = t.oid
    JOIN pg_namespace s on t.relnamespace = s.oid
WHERE a.attnum > 0 
    AND NOT a.attisdropped
    AND LENGTH(a.attname) > 1
    AND s.nspname in ({{schemas}})
```